# How can I properly wrap text in a div next to another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to wrap text on smaller screens like this screenshot

[image]

but my actual result so far is the div only sticking to a new line, like this screenshot

[image]

My html

```
        <section class="alertBlurb">
          <div class="weeklyAlertBlurb">
            Text qm asq x zxcvbn vcxza qwert asdf qwertyu
          </div>
          <div class="waitlistBlurb">
            <a href="https://example.com">
              &nbsp;asdf uyt asdfghj qwe rerytxx zaqwsqwas
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="attendBlurb">
            &nbsp;zxc textt qwe "a zxcv qa asdfgh qwerty" tyh.
          </div>
        </section>
```

& css

```
  .weeklyAlertBlurb {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .waitlistBlurb {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
    @media (max-width: 428px) {
        .waitlistBlurb {
      margin-left: -0.25em;
      }
    }
  .attendBlurb {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
    @media (max-width: 428px) {
        .attendBlurb {
      margin-left: -0.25em;
      }
    }
  section.alertBlurb {
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: -5em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

I've tried different things like word-wrap: break-word;  with no success. I'm wondering if I need to redo my markup structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div tag is a block-level tag, it, of course, starts in a new line, so instead use span tag,

```
<span class="attendBlurb">
            &nbsp;zxc textt qwe "a zxcv qa asdfgh qwerty" tyh.
          </span>
```